# Seblod: Email field

Tags: cck, seblod

I have a question about Seblod. I am using an email field to submit customer requests. I am trying to format the Email as HTML so the agent can easily read it.

While this generally works, I have 2 problems with it.

1. I added a textarea field (not WYSIWYG). I configured this field to replace newlines with paragraphs (`<p>`), when I enter a message with several lines, then in the email they end up as one line. The new lines are just removed, no paragraphs are visible.
2. Similarly, I have added a checkbox field with several options. There is a `separator` field that contains a comma `,` by default. I tried to replace it with `<br/>` but that not allowed. I am also looking for a way to separate the content with newlines or list items or paragraphs in the email.

Currently I have inserted the fields in the email like this:

```
<p>#customer_message#</p>

<p>#customer_checkboxes#</p>
```

Comment: Have you tried other HTML-tags ? Maybe something is preventing the use of HTML at all.